# X11 Unicode KeyEvent Issues

Tags: c++, unicode, x11

The program I'm working on a virtual keyboard of sorts that requires unicode. Using the code I've received from http://goo.gl/pv9ht and it works for normal (ASCII) keysyms when converting to a keycode, but XKeysymToKeycode() returns 0 on a keysym like XK_agrave (include/X11/keysymdefs.h).

I'm also not quite sure how to do the same with capitals. When I try the same with XK_A (that's capital 'A'), it returns the same keycode as 'a'. This does make sense since they are the same keycode (along with a bunch of other characters) according to the output 'xmodmap -pke'. But how do I make it send (XSendKeyEvent) the capital form of the keycode?

Help would be much appreciated.

Comment: Can no longer see the code, please edit question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You send with a modifier key (shift in this case)

So you set XKeyEvent->state |= ShiftMask

> The state member is set to indicate the logical state of the pointer buttons and modifier keys just prior to the event, which is the bitwise inclusive OR of one or more of the button or modifier key masks: Button1Mask, Button2Mask, Button3Mask, Button4Mask, Button5Mask, ShiftMask, LockMask, ControlMask, Mod1Mask, Mod2Mask, Mod3Mask, Mod4Mask, and Mod5Mask.

Source: http://linux.die.net/man/3/xkeyevent

Comment: Thank you. Any idea as to the first part, though?

Comment: As far as I know there is no way to send Unicode key presses using X api.

Comment: Problem solved. I decided to simply send the keycodes of Ctrl+Shift+u+(unicode numbers)+release mods. That's how it works in Ubuntu, at least.

Comment: Scratch that, I ended up using XChangeKeyboardMapping and set an unused keycode (something high) to the unicode keysym I wanted. Then I just sent *that* keycode to the specified window.