# XKeysymToKeycode, XTestFakeKeyEvent and mapping

Tags: keyboard, xorg

I have the following problem:

- I'm trying to send fake key events to the X server.

To do this, I'm aware of two methods:

- XSendEvent - I tried this [tutorial](http://www.doctort.org/adam/nerd-notes/x11-fake-keypress-event.html) with the XK_Z instead of XK_Down

  - Does not work with GTK3
- XTestFakeKeyEvent - See my code below

My problem is, None of this method takes account of the keyboard mapping. I mean, when I select AZERTY mapping I have a "z" character as I expect, when I select the QWERTY mapping I get a "w" and with my beloved BÉPO mapping I get an "é".

How can I get the same character independently of the keyboard mapping??

I'm using Ubuntu 12.10 under Unity.

Here, my code for XTestFakeKeyEvent:

```
#include <X11/Xutil.h>
#include <X11/keysym.h>
#include <X11/extensions/XTest.h>
#include <iostream>
// The key code to be sent.
// A full list of available codes can be found in /usr/include/X11/keysymdef.h
/* g++ -o XFakeKey tst.c -L/usr/X11R6/lib -lX11 -lXtst */

char *text = "z";
main()
{
// Obtain the X11 display.
  Display *display = XOpenDisplay(0);
  if(display == NULL)
    return -1;

  Window focusWindow;
  int revert;
  XGetInputFocus(display, &focusWindow, &revert);
  KeyCode code = XKeysymToKeycode(display, XStringToKeysym(text));

  XTestFakeKeyEvent(display, code, True, CurrentTime);
  XTestFakeKeyEvent(display, code, False, CurrentTime);

  XCloseDisplay(display);
  return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the `XChangeKeyboardMapping` API to bind a unicode Keysym to an unused Keycode.

Then, you send the remapped Keycode (using `XTestFakeKeyEvent` or `XSendEvent`) and applications that use `XKeycodeToKeysym` will get your intended symbol, independent of the current keyboard/IME.

Not tested, but seems to work according to [this comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8675797/x11-unicode-keyevent-issues#comment10808345_8676119).